# Could not find module `ember-cli/test-loader`

Tags: ember-cli

I have recently updated my project to ember-cli@2.8.  I am getting the following error when running thests `ember test`

Does anyone know what the issue might be? I can see it has been removed from [here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/commit/4687fe353ad12cf9ed2ccd224d74f88c3532ff6f).

```
not ok 1 PhantomJS 2.1 - Global error: Error: Could not find module `ember-cli/test-loader` imported from `(require)` at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js, line 228
    ---
        Log: |
            { type: 'error',
              text: 'Error: Could not find module `ember-cli/test-loader` imported from `(require)` at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js, line 228\n' }
```

I have the following in `package.json`

```
"ember-cli-test-loader": "^1.1.0",
```

Comment: I`ve got exactly the same issue, I threw away all bower and node_modules, followed the upgrade steps again but without any luck. Did you solved it somehow ?

Comment: No, still not solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, solved it by inspecting my dependencies for `ember-cli/test-loader`, it happens to be some of my packages rely on older versions on ember and needed to be upgraded.

Comment: Also, can you tell me the dependency that was the culprit?

Comment: I searched for the occurrence of `ember-cli/test-loader` in the source files in `node_modules`and checked which extensions this affected. I used yarn instead of npm and run `yarn upgrade-interactive` for `npm` you can have a chance with `npm outdated`but I didn't used this command ever.

Comment: Updating ember-suave to the latest version has solved this issue for me.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue and looking through my `yarn.lock` file there is nothing pointing at older versions of `ember-cli-test-loader`. We're on the latest (`4.0.1`) version of `ember-suave` and even removing that doesn't help. Any other ideas?

Comment: I found the culprit in our own code! We had some code which added a checkbox for SASS linting to our build and it `require('ember-cli/test-loader')`'d...